# Ask: setInterval for fetch data ReactJS under 1 second impact

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
useEffect(() => {
        const timerId = setInterval(fectData, 500);
    }, []);
```

i want to refresh fetch data under 1 second,or i want get data fastest way, is there any impact in hardware server or client if i set interval under 1 second? Are there any best practices of my problem and what's the impact on my system if I set Interval less than 1 second?

Comment: Why not just use a socket?

Comment: socket? can you give reference about socket?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Comment: https://socket.io/

Comment: what do you want to achieve? What is it I mean that you want to fetch under 1 second? Data updates that often?

Comment: @WahabShah yes, update data so offten so i need realtime as posible

Comment: socket.io? is better then use setinterval?

Answer (score 0):

Using a webSocket or a SSE would be best i guess, but in case you still want to stick to an api call inside of a useEffect, you should at least use add a cleanup function,

```js
useEffect(() => {
        const timerId = setInterval(fectData, 500);
        return () => clearInterval(timerID);
    }, []);
```